# Bootstrap 5 radio button collapse

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have two radio buttons.

[image: radios]

When I select one of the radios, All radios be hidden.

[image: after]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Sector</label>
        <div>
            <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#private" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="private">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sector" id="private" value="0">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="private">Private</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#governmental" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="governmental">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sector" id="governmental" value="1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="governmental">Governmental</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="collapse" id="private">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    You selected Private.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="collapse" id="governmental">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    You selected Governmental.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is why two are opened together,

[image: problem]

I want to open government and close private when I click on the government.

When I click on private, private opens and government close.

Comment: you might try using `governmental` and `private` ids only once. you are using them in both the form and the collapsable groups

Comment: change the ids for form elements to something like `governmental_sector` so that they dont match the ids in the cards. if you look at you `data-bs-target` you can see that the id you are specifying actually exists twice in the document. once in the form as the input, and once in the collapse group.

Comment: @Brenden, Thanks. But why are the two opened together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the ids unique will make the toggles work as designed. The are all individually toggled every time you click the trigger. However, you can tie the toggled groups together using the [parent](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#options) option.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Sector</label>
    <div>
      <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#private" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="private">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sector" id="private_sector" value="0">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="private_sector">Private</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#governmental" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="governmental">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sector" id="governmental_sector" value="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="governmental_sector">Governmental</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="sector_descriptions">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="collapse" id="private" data-bs-parent="#sector_descriptions">
        <div class="card card-body">
          You selected Private.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="collapse" id="governmental" data-bs-parent="#sector_descriptions">
        <div class="card card-body">
          You selected Governmental.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I notice the "You selected .." box collapses/shows if you click the radio button item again. Is there a native Bootstrap way resolve that? E.g. show always show the info box matching the selection.